# I understand why 0 prints 0, and foo! but why doesn't 1 or 2 print anything?

Tags: python

```
for variable in range(20):
    if variable % 4 == 0:
        print variable
    if variable % 16 == 0:
        print 'Foo!'
```

Comment: Because values 1 and 2 do not meet the condition `% 4 == 0` or `% 16 == 0`. What is so unclear about that?

Comment: Thanks, I figured out what I was doing wrong.  I was putting the wrong thing into the shell.,  I put 1 % 4 and not 1 % 4 == 0 to get the boolean answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean 0 behind the equal mark or as a value of `variable`?

As a value of `variable` it can't print anything because neither 1 or 2 are a multitude of 4 or 16. As the second part of the equation, it should print something for `variable == (1 || 2)`.

0 is a multitude of any number as `anything * 0 == 0`

Hope I got your question right.